# What do you think of this analysis for a small dataset with a weird experimental design?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, experiment-design, multiple-comparisons, small-sample

I have a very small dataset (n<30) that is divided in 3 groups: healthy controls, patients with condition A, and patients with condition B. I am going to do a lipidomics analysis of the samples, so that I will have a much larger number of features than samples.

Now, the idea is to get basal lipid concentrations for the three groups and also post-treatment concentrations for A and B. These treatments are T1, T2, and T3. Because of the nature of the conditions, both A and B will get T1, but only A will get T2, and only B will get T3. There will also be a subset of A and B that doesn't receive any treatment.

I know the number of samples and the design itself are whack, but this is what I have and I was not given a choice on the matter. Although I MIGHT be able to argue for treating all samples with the 3 treatments if that could help.

So my idea was to first compare basal A and basal B to the controls and find lipids that are significantly different using t-tests/Mann Whitney U tests. Then I would compare A + T2 vs A w/o T2 vs controls, A + T1 vs A w/o T1 vs controls, B + T3 vs B w/o T3 vs controls, and B + T1 vs B w/o T1 vs controls. I would then compare the proportion of lipids that "improved" (stopped being significantly altered when compared to controls) for patients with treatment vs patients w/o treatment and this would hopefully show if a treatment can make patients more like controls???

Is this too convoluted? Could I use multifactor ANOVA instead? If I did use ANOVA, would I have to perform one ANOVA for each lipid?

Please help :(

The design looks like this:

| Group | Basal | T1 | T2 | T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Control | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 11 | 5 | 6 | 0 |
| B | 14 | 5 | 0 | 9 |

Comment: A table or figure illustrating the number of samples in each treatment combination & time point might help communicate the design to readers.

Comment: @mkt ok, I added a table with the number of samples for each combination